# What is a good data plan for Internet surfing in northern Italy?

Tags: cellphones, italy, data-plans

I've checked the webpages of some their providers, but franly, just like in the case of those in my own language, I literally cannot find my way around them. So if you wouldn't mind sharing a word of two or advice.

I'm looking for a good solution for mobile internet surfing in northern Italy, that can be connected to a laptop (you know, that usb stick with a SIM card inside kind of thing). 15 Gb or so at some decent speed. Can you perhaps give a recommendation or two of what to get?

---

**Edit:** Just to define what I'm looking for exactly. A data plan of 15 Gb with an internet key (usb stick into which a SMS card goes) that you plug into a laptop. Preferably non-contractual, so I can cancel when I leave.
I am not interested in surfing on my mobile phone since due to size I still prefer the smaller Nokia-like models for calls (smaller to carry) - no internet on them.

Answer (score 3):

I think 3 (Tre) is providing good internet in a good price. You are looking for something which is called *chiavetta* in Italy. Are you aiming to use it for a short period? Because if so in my idea it doesn't worth to pay for the modem if you don't own one. Buy the plan for the mobile phone and share it with the laptop.

---

**EDIT**

Well I have some time now and could edit my post to add some more detail;

I have read in your edit that you don't prefer contract. This actually does not work properly in Italy because most of the fair offers are contract-based, and you can rarely find a fair Internet option which does not require a contract.

I have found this option that might suit your needs (which in fact needs a contract, *abbonamento* in Italian):
http://www.tre.it/tariffe/web-senza-limiti

Some notes about this option:

The discount from 19E to 14E is only given if you purchase an iPad Mini or Samsung Galaxy Tab from them;

After finishing 15 GB/month OR 500 MB/day traffic, you will need to pay 20 cents for each 100 MB extra usage;

If there is not access to 3G network (HSPDA) and it switches to GPRS it will cost 30 cents for each 100 MB usage.

Comment: Please, if you find the time. I'm looking for something to use for a period of up to two or three months. In Croatia, I had an USB stick (modem) and inside you put a SIM card and it works on a laptop. Don't know the technical details but if you're not staying somewhere for a prolonged period of time, it's a very practical solution. I'll try to find some more info on chiavetta in the meantime.

Comment: Are you talking about this offer: http://www.tre.it/promozioni/internet-mobile/chiavetta-tre-it-42. This seems to be 3 GB for 5 EUR a month. Is it pre-paid?

Comment: @Kozuch yes that would be another possibility however he already owns a key and wouldn't prefer to pay for the key again I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you the 3 (H3G) offer. 
http://www.tre.it/promozioni/internet-mobile/chiavetta-tre-it-42

The USB key will cost you 29 euros plus 5 euros / month for 3GB of data (SuperInternet option). It should be a prepaid plan, so if you stop paying and the credit goes to zero you have nothing more to pay, the "SuperInternet" option will just be disabled.

I have a Nexus 5 with H3G data plan (SuperInternet) and I'm really happy with it. :)

Comment: So, if I understand properly would be 29 euros for the key, and 25 euros / 15 gb of data, with no additional obligations? Sounds silly, but learned to check everything with telecom operators. Lots of small print :)

Comment: yep. the 25 euros are divided for months. So you will have a maximum of 3GB of data (max 100MB per day, for 30 days) at 5 euros / month.

Answer (score 2):

I'll totally suggest WIND it is cheap, nice customer service plus you can buy cheap phones down there to put the card in. Well...you might think of getting Fastweb as well 'cause skype works better with them the only problem is that they do not have phisical shops where you can walk in. You need to call a special phone and get the card shipped . Or if you want to skip the cellphone option you could use an [internet key](http://www.clasf.it/chiavetta-fastweb-kay-in-caserta-10283617/) like these ones here (buy them used).

Anything else just write back

Comment: Yes, those Internet keys are what I had in mind. I'm not interested in surfing on my mobile phone, since due to weight and size constrains I prefer "dumb" models (old Nokia lookalikes, with the keyboard). I've looked at WIND page, but have been unable to find anything close to a 15Gb no-contract option ... only small packages (3Gb or so).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Vodafone or Wind as operators. Tre has a bad coverage outside big cities, you might ask people in your area about that.

You can buy a "SIM dati" in any mobile phone shop, it's a SIM card only enabled for internet.  For example this [SIM dati Vodafone](http://www.vodafone.it/portal/Privati/Tablet-e-Chiavette/Tutte-le-offerte/sim-piani-internet) offers 15 Gb for 35 euros/month or 7 Gb for 20 euros. Unfortunately I think it's a recurring plan, with minimum duration of 1 or 2 years. (Those info are hard to find for us italians too).

Another way would be to buy a regular "pay-as-you-go" SIM and add an internet plan like ["Internet Big" for the Wind "All Inclusive" plan](http://www.wind.it/it/privati/tariffe_e_opzioni/internet/per_smartphone/internet_big_per_all_inclusive_e_noi/), about 11 euros/month for 3 Gb, you can easily de-activate the SIM once you're leaving the country.

The fastest speed you can get is HDSPA, some areas are covered with 4G network.

You plan to travel along all northern Italy or will you stay in only one place?
Another option would be to go to a mobile phone store (there's plenty of them everywhere) and ask. If you're lucky enough you will find a clerk with a good english, get all the informations you need and buy the best internet plan for your needs. =)

Comment: I would prefer not to go into contract. Is there a prepay (month to month) option like that "Internet Big" option but for 15Gb with any of the operators? I will be using it in Bergamo, since I don't intend to carry my laptop with me outside the city.

Comment: "Internet Big" is also available for prepaid SIM. If you buy an Internet Key from Wind, you have 3Gb/month for 9 euro/month. http://www.wind.it/it/internetmobile/pagina282.phtml?sez=InternetPromo

Comment: Plans change name and/or details about every couple of months, it's crazy. Go for a walk in the centre of Bergamo and enter a Wind/Vodafone/Tre store. IMHO it's the best choice.