# Wi-fi coverage in Taormina and Palermo

Tags: italy, wifi, sicily

Does anyone know how good is the wi-fi coverage in `Taormina` or `Palermo`? We're planning a trip to Sicily and I want to make sure I can work from there.

Comment: the main problem with italian sim cards is that they don't offer a flat rate but only a bunch of MB each day

Comment: This can be helpful: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24431/what-is-a-good-data-plan-for-internet-surfing-in-northern-italy  Mobile providers offer the same prices all over the country. Mobile network coverage or quality can vary greatly between areas. I'm not aware of Sicily.

Comment: Removed your second half, as multiple questions should be separated, and it was also asking for recommended (See [help] - these are not usually on topic)

Comment: @GuidoPreite: Are SIM cards related to Wi-Fi? Surely they're instead related to 3G/4G?

Comment: @hippietrail my comment was about the second part of the question that has been edited (you can check the edit history)

Answer (score 2):

I can talk about the wifi coverage there.  What I've been doing recently to determine speed of connections is to use Instabridge (not my app) - a free app for Android, that does two very important things:

- Shows where open wifi is (including password-protected ones which have been crowd-sourced - e.g. a kind soul has added his home wifi to the list). This is displayed on a map.
- For most of the access points shown, a tested speed for the connection is displayed as well. This quickly shows you at a glance where the fast wifi connections are.

Skimming across the map myself, I can see at least one connection of 1Mbps in Palermo - not the quickest, I guess, but reasonable for some stuff.  That'd give you some indication.